# How to estimate transation fee, gas limit, storage limit through ConseilJS?

Tags: fee, conseiljs

When using ConseilJS to send transaction, you need to assign transaction fee, storage limit, gas limit manually. So how to estimate transaction fee, gas/storage limit before sending the transaction to network? Could someone give me some example by ConseilJS code? Or which interface of ConseilJS should I invoke?

Answer (score 1):

Try `TezosNodeWriter.testContractInvocationOperation`. You can read its documentation [here](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/d65a7aed76d5d918b9daaf995470eb88b5f9baf4/src/chain/tezos/TezosNodeWriter.ts#L551). You can find it used in an example [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymoussprocket/148d82fc9bf6c413be04155a90d57be6).